# How can I redirect to a new page with a Qt QML WASM application without being blocked by pop up blocker?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6

I have a Qt QML WASM application that is basically a form that submits to a remote server which responds with a redirect.   Use case is a more advanced pre-checkout form that is passing information to a backend for Stripe Checkout (which is the url redirect)

If I use: `Qt.openUrlExternally(response.redirectUrl);` It is flagged as a pop up on mobile. I'm wishing to do the traditional redirect of the page without it being considered a popup.   Currently the app is full screen WASM with QML.

Comment: I wonder what kind of response you expect without even providing [mcve]?

Comment: @folibis While having a [mcve] would be _nice_, and might allow someone curious here to debug the issue, I think anyone who knows the answer to "How to get around `Qt.openUrlExternally` opening a popup when targeting WASM" can easily answer this based on the given information.

Comment: @hyde I admit that I have no experience with WASM (if not as a user). In the QML context, `openUrlExternally` works similarly to QDesktopServices.openUrl(), and in the WASM case the "open in external application" considers the underlying "OS" (that "opens" the url) as the browser, which is probably why it attempts to create a popup. Still, knowing the WASM environment (including the page in which it's loaded) can provide some context, since it's strictly related to the underlying JS loading/WASM engine/browser capabilities/etc.